# default argument value of Number.toPrecision()

Tags: javascript

Have been wondering recently how browser console or node.js shell print the number always in a right precision. E.g. number `0.1` is not printed like something `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`, but `1.234567890123` or likes are printed fully. I think it is using `Number.toPrecision()` (correct me if wrong). What is the default value used as a parameter, does it depends on the printed number itself?

Comment: I think `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` is outside the precision of JavaScript numbers

Comment: @evolutionxbox but this is how unbounded printing would print 0.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: `0.10000000000000006` will print fine, but `0.100000000000000006` (one extra zero) will be truncated to `0.10000000000000000` which is the same as `0.1`

Comment: Without an argument, `.toPrecision()` is basically `.toString()`.